# Hashtable <String,Object> returning null

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I made a Hashtable where key(id) is a string and the value is an object ,

```
public void addSpot(String id) {
        Spot spot = new Spot(id);
        SpotMap.addSpot(id, spot); // adds spot to table
        spot.getMarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(28, 30));
        spot.addMark(map); // adds mark to map
            Log.i("SPOT_TABLE", SpotMap.getSize());
    }

    public void removeSpot(String id) {
        try{
        Spot spot=SpotMap.getSpotMap().get(id);
        spot.removeMark(spot.getMarker());
        SpotMap.removeSpot(id);
            Log.i("SPOT_TABLE", SpotMap.getSize());}
        catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

this is the SpotMap class

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.myapp.Spot;

public class SpotMap {

    private static Hashtable<String, Spot> spotMap = new Hashtable();

    public static Hashtable<String, Spot> getSpotMap() {
        return spotMap;
    }

    // public static void setMarkermap(Hashtable<String, Spot> markermap) {
    // MarkerMap.markerMap = markermap;
    // }

    public static void addSpot(String id, Spot spot) {
        spotMap.put(id, spot);

    }

    public static void removeSpot(String id) {
        spotMap.remove(id); // removes spot from table
    }

    public static void printTable(){
        Enumeration key = spotMap.keys();
        while (key.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(spotMap.get(key.nextElement())); 

        }
    }
}
```

the Spot class

```
package com.example.myapp;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

    public class Spot {
        private String id;
        private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
        private Marker marker;

        public Spot(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setMarkerOptions(MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            this.markerOptions = markerOptions;
        }

        public void addMark(GoogleMap map) {
            marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

        public void removeMark(Marker marker) {
            marker.remove();

        }

        public MarkerOptions getMarkerOptions() {
            return markerOptions;
        }

        public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
            this.marker = marker;
        }

        public Marker getMarker() {
            return marker;
        }
        /*
         * public Spot getSpot() { return this; }
         */
        public String toString(){
            return id;

        }
    }
```

the app works well when I add  1 spot and removes it , but when  I add  2 consecutive spots(with same id) and call the remove function , I get NullPointException and it doesn't remove the mark
LogCat

```
01-23 10:10:36.698: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:38.518: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 0
01-23 10:10:40.098: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:40.718: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:41.748: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:42.638: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 0
01-23 10:10:44.488: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:45.048: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 0
01-23 10:10:48.628: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:48.938: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:49.368: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:49.448: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:49.708: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:50.678: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 1
01-23 10:10:50.938: I/SPOT_TABLE(5209): 0
```

the LogCat prints the size of the Hashtable , and as you can see , adding same key replaces the old one as usual , also remove button seems to work ... but now I think it's a marker issue

Comment: Empty catch blocks are the root of all evil.

Comment: Step 1 would be to not swallow a possible exception you are getting in your method, but at least print the stacktrace.

Comment: Do you mean that you add two spots with same id and you try to remove both? In that case only the last spot will be present in the HashTable, as there cannot be two objects with same key in a HashTable.

Comment: Am using android so stacktrace , system.out.println not working but ... in LogCat i get NullPointerException when I call the remove function after adding two spots with same ID

Comment: @sthor69  yes , the second one replaces the first one , but then when I try to remove it , I get NullPointerException (without the try/catch)

Comment: Can you see from the LogCat where is the line where the exception is thrown? Can you post the LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `addMarker()` method returns `null` when you try to add a `Marker` a second time.

This will cause your `marker` instance variable to become `null`, giving you a `NullPointerException` in your `removeSpot()` method.

Comment: public final Marker addMarker (MarkerOptions options) 
Returns
The Marker that was added to the map.

Comment: I think the Spot is correctly removed from the Hashtable , but the Marker is not removed for some reason , @Keppil

Answer (score 0):

It's working now , I had to edit the addSpot function , to remove old entery before inserting the new one
but until now , I don't know why

```
spot.removeMark(spot.getMarker());
```

wasn't working correctly

```
  public void addSpot(String id) {
            Spot spot = new Spot(id);
            if (SpotMap.getSpotMap().containsKey(id)) {
                removeSpot(id);
            }
            spot.getMarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(28, 30));
            SpotMap.addSpot(id, spot); // adds spot to table
            spot.addMark(map); // adds mark to map
            Log.i("SPOT_TABLE", SpotMap.getSize());
        }
```